# git push not showing changes in the remote repository

Tags: git

I have a non bare remote repository setup in my server, and when I push from local to the repository, the changes are not made.

I have tried to checkout master (which is the only branch in my repository) in the server, I can not see the change. When I check the commit log, I can see the change being committed, but when I display the file it is not there.

I have managed to make it work by committing in the server's working directory, which undos the change, and then revert the commit and the change I want is made. However I don't want to be forced to do this every change.

I understand pushing to a non-bare directory is bad practice but I really wish to know what's going wrong here.
code below shows the commit that should be effective.

```sh
$ git log -p
commit <>

    Update 404.php

diff --git a/404.php b/404.php
index f9c7b83..8c6222e 100644
--- a/404.php
+++ b/404.php
@@ -30,5 +30,5 @@ get_header(); ?>

 <?php radiate_sidebar_select(); ?>
 <?php get_footer();
-
+//test
 ?>
```

edit:
after push:

```sh
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 517 bytes | 517.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://my-server.com/project
   37e5fbf..3fa8049  master -> master
```

Comment: When you push to the server, what is the output?

Comment: As @JakeWorth is hinting at, the push should have given you an error. If it didn't, something funny is going on. What happens if you go on the remote and do `git checkout 3fa8049`? (I expect: you'll see your changes, but Git should tell you you're in detached HEAD state.)

Comment: @joanis I tried `git checkout 3fa8049` it does say I am in a detached head state however the change is not there

Comment: And in your sandbox, does commit `3fa8049` really contain your changes? I just noticed something weird: your `git log -p` output shows `commit <>`. Is that literal? I normally get a sha1 on the `commit` line in my git logs. To me it smells like you didn't really push what you meant to push.